# Approximate function as $x$ tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I'm looking for a way to approximate the following function $f$ as $x \to \infty$
$$
f = \ln \left( 1 + e^{a_1 x} + e^{a_2 x} + A e^{(a_1+a_2) x} \right)
$$
where $a_1$, $a_2$ and $A$ are constants. Any hints would be much appreciated.

---

To better clarify what I'm looking for:

For instance, the following function
$$
g = \ln \left(1 + e^{a_1x} \right)
$$
can be approximated for $x \to \infty$ as follows
$$
 \displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln \left(1 + e^{a_1x} \right) \approx \ln \left(e^{a_1x} \right) = a_1x
$$

---

(I'm not sure what tags should be used for this question, so any suggestions are welcome.)

Comment: Divide through by $e^{(a_1 + a_2)x}$, you get

$$f = (a_1 + a_2) x + \ln(e^{-(a_1 + a_2)x} + e^{-a_2 x} + e^{-a_1 x} + A)$$

and as 

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(e^{-(a_1 + a_2)x} + e^{-a_2 x} + e^{-a_1 x} + A) = \ln(A)$$

then as $x \to \infty, \ \ f \approx (a_1 + a_2)x + \ln(A)$

Comment: @Mattos thank you! If you post it as answer, then I'll probably accept it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that my solution only works if $a_1, a_2 > 0$, otherwise it's incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach is to characterize $\ln(a+b)$ for $a,b>0$. A little manipulation and... $$\ln(a+b) = \ln(a(1 + b/a)) = \ln a + \ln(1+ b/a)$$ Use the above to separate the logarithm in the expression for $f$ and use $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(1+e^{a_1x}) \approx \ln(e^{a_1x})$$ to remove the $1$ at each iteration. I'll let you solve the problem for yourself; the end behaviour will depend on your constants, particularly $A$. The choice $A=1$ yields a pretty result.

Comment: Thank you! I'll wait for a bit to accept your answer to give other people a chance as well.

Comment: The cases $A=0$ and $A=0,a_1=a_2$ may require special treatment.